# Function returning iterators to construct STL containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I am tasked to write a function that does some sort of tokenization operation on a string and to return a begin and end iterable that can be used to construct any STL container by the calling code. How can this be acheived in C++? Any clues/ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In C++14, in order to be usable as a source of data for a STL container, an iterator must fulfill the [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) named requirement.

In other words, it must be a struct or class that has all of the members that are required by that specification.

Once you have built such a type, then it's just a matter of creating a function that will create two of them: One that references the first element, and another one that refers to "one-past" the last element.

In the end you will end up with something roughly like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MyInputIterator {
  // Announce that this is an input iterator
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag; 
  
  // Announce the type of elements being iterated over.
  using value_type = std::string;

  // For the sake of this use-case, these three can be 
  // treated as "unfortunately necessary". 
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using reference = value_type&;
  using pointer = value_type*;

  // You mostly just have to implement the three following methods.
  bool operator!=(const MyInputIterator&) const;
  MyInputIterator& operator++();
  value_type operator*() const; 

  // N.B. For a pure input iterator, having operator*() return by value is 
  // often preferable, but returning by reference is required for other iterator
  // categories.
};

std::pair<MyInputIterator, MyInputIterator> tokenize(const std::string&);

int main() {
  auto tok_ite_pair = tokenize("hi there");

  std::vector<std::string> tokens(result.first, result.second); 
}
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Let me toy around and see if I can achieve what I want. I would have thought this kind of thing would be more common. Thanks

Comment: @user1408865 To be fair, in C++20, implementing the `std::input_iterator` concept is a fair bit cleaner and more straightforward. But for C++14, you have to use this mechanism which goes all the way back to c++98